# Mysql - yet another select count from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Tried loads of options form answers here. I am sorry guys - I was not able to get correct data out of Db so...
I have two tables. One (**`books`**)  contains IDs

```
book_id
52
49
1
49
1
49
```

Another table (**`authors`**) contains names for the IDs (i.e id 52 = 'Dumas', 49 = 'Tolkien' etc)

I'd like to count all the occurences and return results as:

```
Author - Number of Occurences
----------------------------
Dumas | 12
-----------------------------
Tolkien | 8
etc
```

I can count all occurences using this query:

```
SELECT book_id,COUNT(*) as count FROM `books` GROUP BY `book_id` ORDER BY count DESC
```

This works well but returns (obviously) results as **ID : Occurrences** while I need **Name: Occurrences**

Comment: you need to learn joins.

Comment: looks like yes, I do need and definitely will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that author table has the author´s ID since it´s a many to one relationship where one author can be related to many books. In that case you can try this query:

```
    SELECT author_name, COUNT(*) as count 
    FROM `books`JOIN author on book_id = author_id
    GROUP BY `author_name` 
    ORDER BY count DESC
```

For avoiding problems with authors with the same name, you can try this one:

```
    SELECT author_id, author_name, COUNT(*) as count 
    FROM `books`JOIN author on book_id = author_id
    GROUP BY author_id, `author_name` 
    ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Luis!
damn.. gotta grab MYSQL book and study it properly as I assume my question is silly =( Thanks, man!

Comment: This will not work for authors with same name (or not?). It's very late here so i cannot think very well..

Comment: use group by author_id.

Answer (score -1):

Make a nested `SELECT` using `GROUP BY` and then you join the results this with the original table. The following query will work properly with the following schema:

**books**

```
id     author_id    name
```

**authors**

```
id     name
```

**Query: **(working for authors with same name too)

```
SELECT bb.name, _aa.count
FROM book AS aa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT book_id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM book
    GROUP BY book_id
) AS _aa
ON aa.book_id = _aa.book_id
INNER JOIN authors AS bb
ON aa.author_id = bb.id
ORDER BY _aa.count DESC;
```

Comment: a simple join with a group by will suffice. That is just unnecessarily complex considering the OP knows very little about sql

Comment: @khuderm you are wrong. Selecting columns that are not in group by may lead at wrong results https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html. Also the accepted answer will not work for authors who have same name.

Comment: in his use case, group by works perfectly fine. are there 2 authors with the exact same name? most likely not.

Comment: mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly: http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/